Looking for a film similar to Groundhog Day with a woman reliving her wedding day over and over until she marries her fiance's brother instead
This is about a lady who is marrying a guy who she realises she doesn't really love and she ends up meeting a stranger while taking a walk in the woods near the cabin where she is due to get married and meets her fiancee's brother unknowingly. 
This is like ground hog day where she wakes her on her wedding day at the same time and keeps getting married till she gets things right. 
Every day she meets with the brother and gets to know him only her remembering the time spent together but not him. Eventually she ends up marrying the brother and tells him whats been happening and the next day becomes a new day after they're married as she is the one who she is meant to be with. 
It was definitely on the Movies 24 channel on sky.

Looks like you're looking for the Hallmark Channel original film I Do, I Do, I Do

A young lady gets engaged to the "perfect man". The groom's mother plans everything for the wedding (in a week). The wedding is over the top when it was supposed to be small and elegant. It turns out to be a miserable day for the bride and she wishes for a do-over. She gets her wish over and over until she finally realizes exactly what she wants

The official Hallmark Channel page for the film with additional footage can be visited here.
Preview here:



